# How to describe or further isolate this apparent Webkit SVG bug?

Tags: webkit, svg

I pared down some odd behavior I was experiencing in SVG and I came up with [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/vXGm7/):

```xml
<circle  r="10" />
<rect    width="18" height="18" />
<polygon points="10,20 30,30 40,15 25,10" />
<script>
var svg = document.querySelector('svg'),
    els = document.querySelectorAll('svg *');
for (var i=els.length;i--;){
  var el = els[i];
  el._dragXForm = el.transform.baseVal.appendItem(svg.createSVGTransform());
  setInterval((function(el){
    return function(){
      var tx = el._dragXForm.matrix;
      tx.e += Math.random()*2-1;
      tx.f += Math.random()*2-1;        
    }
  })(el),50);
}
</script>
```

In Safariv5 and Chromev18 on OS X the circle and polygon both jitter, but the rect does not. It does nothing. The `SVGMatrix` is getting a new value, but the appearance on screen is not updated. (In Firefox, it works as expected.)

If I change the script to remove `_dragXForm` [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/vXGm7/1/):

```js
for (var i=draggables.length;i--;){
  var el = draggables[i];
  el.transform.baseVal.appendItem(svg.createSVGTransform());
  setInterval((function(el){
    return function(){
      var tx = el.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix;
      tx.e += Math.random()*2-1;
      tx.f += Math.random()*2-1;        
    }
  })(el),50);
}
```

…then the `<rect>` moves along with the others.

Besides seeming like an insane bug (how can this only affect a `<rect>`?!) I feel that this has not yet isolated the source of the bug.

**What's the simplest possible code that can reproduce this odd behavior?** (And if there's already a bug filed for this, I'd love to know about it.)

Answer (score 0):

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/vXGm7/2/) appears to be getting closer to the heart of the matter:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg'),
    els = document.querySelectorAll('svg *');
for (var i=els.length;i--;){
  var el = els[i],
      tx = el.transform.baseVal.appendItem(svg.createSVGTransform());
  console.log( el.tagName, tx===el.transform.baseVal.getItem(0) );
  setTimeout((function(el,tx){
    return function(){
      console.log( el.tagName, tx===el.transform.baseVal.getItem(0) );
    }
  })(el,tx),1);
}
```

Output:

```
polygon true  // The return value of appendItem is the same as the first item
rect true     // The return value of appendItem is the same as the first item
circle true   // The return value of appendItem is the same as the first item

polygon true  // The returned value is STILL the same as the first item
rect false    // The returned value is NO LONGER the same as the first item
circle true   // The returned value is STILL the same as the first item
```